# Custom Profile Center Page hosted in Cloudpage

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

I'm trying to create a custom ***Profile Center*** & **Subscription Center** page (where I can apply my HTML and CSS deisgns), which the user can update his or her *Personal Information*, *My Preference* and *Unsubscribe From All*.

Also, i would like it to be placed on CloudPages, is this possible?

A sample code or study guide links would be great for me to study it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We built a Cloud Page set that updates the master-subscribe (AllSubscribers) and Publication Lists and passes/retrieves information from Sales Cloud as well, so this is surely possible.

Processing is done with [AMPscript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/index.htm) and some [SSJS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_serverSideJavaScript.htm), so I'd advise to get familar with these two first. 
There's also an option to write [SOAP API / AMPscript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_a_custom_profile_center_using_ampscript_and_the_soap_api.htm) variation as well, though this is a bit tricky.

Adam has provided a nice clean boilerplate code to start with in [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/wvpv/19777e1167d6ac91e2e8), check that one out if you're not sure how to start off.

In addition I've seen many variations of fully-built custom profile/subscription center code sets posted in github, so if you try to search you'll probably find even more examples.

For an example - a fully built [custom preference center](https://github.com/sfmcdg/sfmc-cloudpages/blob/master/preference-centre/autism-crc/autism-preference-center.html) code in Github.

Hope this helps.